# How to prompt the user for an action

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i have implemented remove functionality to a controller using http method DELETE. What I am intending to do next is to prompt the user if he realy wants to remove or delete that 
item or product.

is such action is possible and achievable using spring MVC?? please let me know how?

**code_1**:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product/remove")
public class RemoveProductPageController {

public final static String sRemoveProductFromListAttributeName = "removeProductFromList";

public final static String CONTROLLER_URL = "/product/remove";
public final static String DO_REMOVE_HANDLER_METHOD_URL = CONTROLLER_URL + "/{idx}";

@Autowired
private ProductService productService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{idx}", 
        method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> doRemove(@Validated @Size(min = 0) @PathVariable(required = true) int idx,
        Model model) {

    Product productToBeRemove = productService.getProductFromListByIdx(idx);
    if (productToBeRemove == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("no product is avaialble at index:" + idx, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    model.addAttribute(RemoveProductPageController.sRemoveProductFromListAttributeName, productToBeRemove);
    productService.removeProdcutFromListBxIdx(idx);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("product removed from index: " + idx, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the jsp page where you intend to show the data and link for delete you can add below code:

```
onclick="return confirm('Confirm Deletion?')"
```

And give href link as the link for the delete.
Example explained clearly in below link:

http://learningprogramming.net/java/spring-mvc/delete-data-from-database-with-spring-data-jpa-in-spring-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use Javascript, then you can direct the user to a second page used for confirmation. Pass along all the form data, etc. that you gathered from the first page. The second page will display the relevant info and ask the user to confirm or cancel. The controller class will then execute the deletion if the user confirmed, or will abort if the user cancelled.